# Sending SMS in java via SMPP protocol

Tags: java, macos, sms-gateway, smpp, opensmppbox

I am new to SMPP protocol. Please kindly advice me what are needed to build java project to send sms via SMPP protocol. How to setup SMPP server and SMPP clients? Need to setup SMS Gateway? If so how to install it? What is OpenSMPPBox?

Answer (score 1):

Loot at this Twitter's Java project https://github.com/twitter/cloudhopper-smpp. It has both server and client parts.

SMPPSim http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/user-guide.htm is a great simple SMPP simulator. Written in Java.

smppsink https://github.com/PowerMeMobile/smppsink is also a simulator, but allows to give instructions to the simulator, for example what submit or delivery status to return. Written in Erlang.